# Logstash uses current year for timestamp without year and shows events with future dates

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have logs wherein there's no year mentioned, and while parsing, logstash adds current year and makes the event appear in future dates.

i checked on forums for a similar issue but unfortunately, there wasn't any solution for it. Based on the discussions, the date filter should automatically put the correct year but its not happening in my case. Below is a sample of log timestamp.

`Tue Oct 20 11:04:30.996 data: zone1 data: zone2` this is log date from Oct 2020.

And the output i get is

```
          "new" => 2021-10-19T08:04:30.996Z,
      "logtime" => "Tue Oct 20 11:04:30.996",
         "path" => "/home/zone.log",
      "message" => "Tue Oct 20 11:04:30.996 data: zone1 data: zone2",
```

Grok/date filter is:

```
grok
        {
        match => { "message" => "(?<logtime>%{DAY} %{MONTH} %{MONTHDAY} %{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}) ........" }
        }

        date
        {
        match =>  [ "logtime", "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"  ] 
        target => "new"
        }
```

There's no dateparsefailure but the timestamp goes into future. Please advise on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date filter cannot possibly know the correct year in all cases. An [issue](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-date/issues/51) for this has been open on github for several years and there is much discussion there about how to fix it. However, I do not expect it will be addressed.

The [parser](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-date/blob/815a4dc7a6d718feefe6eb9e67dc5234495f298d/src/main/java/org/logstash/filters/parser/JodaParser.java#L112) has some heuristics to guess the right year:

- If the timestamp is from December and the current date is in January, assume it is from last year.
- If the timestamp is from January and the current date is in December, assume it is from next year.
- Otherwise use the current year.

If that logic does not work for you then you would have to implement your own logic, probably in a ruby filter, to decide which year to add to the timestamp before parsing it with a date filter.

If you just want to delete events in the future you could use

```
ruby { code => 'if Time.now.to_f < event.get("@timestamp").to_f ; event.cancel ; end' }
```

Comment: i have log which starts from Feb 2020 and is continuing to July 2021 date. If i am to make a ruby, i am a bit confused as there will be two Feb ( one from 2020 and one from 2021 ) to let a year pass into date filter.

Comment: That is a difficult problem. You know that the file starts in Feb 2020, but nothing in the file tells you that. You would have to write ruby code that initially adds 2020 to the timestamp, but when it sees the month flip from December to January increments the year that it adds. That should work even if the file contains data from three years.

Comment: Noted. Other option i am considering is to drop the events where the logtime shows any future timestamp.
` init => "require 'time'"
  code => "if ( (event.get('new').to_i) > (event.get('@timestamp').to_i) ) 
    event.cancel
 end"
`
Can you advise on this?

Comment: Update answer to include how to do that.

Comment: That worked. Breaking down the issue further, can we DROP events which are 5/6 months old based on the log's timestamp? This would allow to not get events beyond Jan, ( since we are in Jul ) and preserve date order. Please advise. 
`
ruby {
  init => "require 'time'"
  code => "if event['@timestamp'] < ( Time.now - 10368000 ) 
    event.cancel
  end"
}

`

Comment: Something like that should work. You do not need the init option.

Comment: i am trying this 
` code => "if ( Time.now.to_f - 10368000 ) < ( event.get('new').to_f ) ` but the parsing starts from Jan 2021 and stops at March 2021. Am i doing it differently?

Comment: This is pretty much a different question now.

Comment: I understand, have posted another question for this.